# ASP MVC 3 switching language with ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization

In an ASP MVC 3 project i want to enable language switching.

The routing is defined like this:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
             "DefaultWithLanguage", // Route name
             "{language}/{controller}/{id}/{slug}", // URL with parameters
             new { language = "en", controller = "Front", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional, slug = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults                 
         );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Trying to switch languages (in _Layout.cshtml) works like this:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Spanish", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), new { language = "es" })</li>
```

Instead of getting a URL like the following (after having selected Spanish)

```
.../es/ControllerName/ActionName
```

i 'm getting this:

```
.../ControllerName/ActionName?Length=11
```

If i set the ActionLink to the following (notice the last null parameter):

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Spanish", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), new { language = "es" }, null)</li>
```

i get this:

```
 .../ControllerName/ActionName?language=es
```

What am i missing?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you leave the Default route as well? Please show all your route registrations.

Comment: @Darin Have a look at the (changed) formulation. I have included all the code in RegisterRoutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with your routes registration `DefaultWithLanguage` route registration. It doesn't allow you to specify the `{action}`. This means that this route will only match a `Details` action (since you have specified it in the default values). Another issue is that you made the `{id}` parameter optional. But that's impossible. Only the **last** parameter of a route can be optional. In your case it is followed by a `{slug}` parameter.

So one possibility is the following:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "DefaultWithLanguage",
        "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new 
        { 
            language = "en", 
            controller = "Front", 
            action = "Details", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional 
        }
    );
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Spanish", 
    ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action"), 
    ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller"),
    new { language = "es" },
    null
)
```

If you wanted to add a `{slug}` parameter then your `{id}` can no longer be optional:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "DefaultWithLanguage",
        "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{slug}",
        new 
        { 
            language = "en", 
            controller = "Front", 
            action = "Details", 
            slug = UrlParameter.Optional 
        }
    );
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    "Spanish", 
    ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action"), 
    ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller"),
    new { 
        language = "es", 
        id = ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("id") 
    },
    null
)
```

Comment: Now i see! You 're right! Thanks very much for the explanation!I 'll give this a try!

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow up to Darin's answer.

I want to have routes like this:

```
.../en/ControllerName/Id
.../en/ControllerName/Id/Slug
.../en/ControllerName
```

This last route causes the problem (see the answer of Darin). The "hack" to keep getting this routes is to define also another route (the second named DefaultWithLanguageWithoutId) :

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                 "DefaultWithLanguage", // Route name
                 "{language}/{controller}/{id}/{slug}", // URL with parameters
                 new { language = "en", controller = "Front", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional, slug = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults                                                   
             );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "DefaultWithLanguageWithoutId", // Route name
                "{language}/{controller}", // URL with parameters
                new { language = "en", controller = "Front", action = "Details"} // Parameter defaults                 

            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
        }
```

This is causing the code to be adjusted in the master page to the following

```
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Deutsch", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()
, ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), new { language = "de"
, id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]!=null ? ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString():null }, null)</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("English", ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()
, ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), new { language = "en"
, id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] != null ? ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString() : null }, null)</li>
```

Works perfect!

The only "drawback" is the fact that there is some code involved (i would have liked to avoid) in the view, but i think it is worth since it is very simple!